# Day click event on Calendar Ext.calendar.panel.Panel

Tags: extjs

I have a calendar panel component:

```
{
            xtype: 'calendar',
            views: {
                week: null,
                day: null
            }
        }
```

How can I define the listeners to trigger an action when the user clicks a day in the monthly-view calendar?

Thanks.

I haven't found a complete implementation example of this component.